# Eclipse Juno failing to start with Java returning 1 error report

Tags: windows, java, eclipse

I have been using Eclipse Juno on windows 8 without any issues until yesterday when, upon starting Eclipse it shows the initial splash screen and then shows the following message:

```
---------------------------
Eclipse
---------------------------
Java was started but returned exit code=1
C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0.v201206081400\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 13f4_5c
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
-----------------
```

At this point Eclipse does not load any further. I have attempted to re-install the Java JDK and JRE without having any effect. I have also re-downloaded Eclipse Juno and run it as a 'fresh' startup which has until now worked initially yesterday

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/q/479394/143655