# Windows 8 hiding java.exe and other files in System32

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-8

I am running Windows 8 Professional and I am trying to run Eclipse as a non-administrator user without success.
Eclipse terminates with "JVM Terminated, Error code 2".

Eclipse tries to use %SYSTEM32%\javaw.exe inspite of JAVA_HOME being set to %PROGRAM_FILES%\Java\jdk1.7.0_07.

I have a non-administrator user account and when I type `dir c:\windows\system32\java*` it results in "File Not Found".

Here is where it gets strange. If I open a command prompt as Administrator and type the same command I get:

```
Directory of C:\Windows\System32
09/24/2012  10:16 AM           188,904 java.exe
09/24/2012  10:16 AM           189,416 javaw.exe
09/24/2012  10:16 AM           289,768 javaws.exe
```

I have full read and execute access in %SYSTEM32% as my normal user, but I only see 2414 files in System32 as opposed to 3107 if running as administrator.

What is going on and is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I got Eclipse to run by editing the eclipse.ini file to point to the JDK by using the -vm switch. But I still cannot understand why I cannot access java in System32 as non-admin user.

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit system, with Eclipse running as 32-bit? `%SYSTEM32%` points to `C:\Windows\SysWoW64` in such a scenario. (This is used for the Windows-on-Windows abstraction layer that supports the cross-architecture functionality, or at least it did in windows vista/windows XP)

Comment: @DarthAndroid: That should be an answer!

Comment: Deleting java*.exe from \Windows\System32 solved problems with all other apps too.

Android SDK installer for instance tried to use \Windows\System32\java* instead of looking at JAVA_HOME or PATH which made it fail.

But, the question remains why Windows 8 hides java.exe if it is in \Windows\System32.

Comment: Ah! I changed the setting "Protect system files" in Explorer, but didn't open a new CMD.EXE. Now the java files appear.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it as follows:

- In Windows 8 » Control Panel » User Account » Turned Off User Access Control.
- Created a directory called : `c:\apps`
- Installed JDK to c:\apps\java; The installed jre to `c:\apps\java\jre\`
- Installed Eclipse for Java Developers to `c:\apps\eclipse`
- Started eclipse.exe by right clicking and running as Administrator.
- Eclipse started.

Confirmed all is OK by building and running a "Hello World" Java project.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8 it is necessary to install both the x86 and x64 versions of Java. You can download them [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp). If you try install Java from your browser (using autodetect from the web page), Java will only install the x86 version.